# Missing DLL in Unity. System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity project that works great on my stationary PC, it can publish to my Android device with no problems.

Since I will be travelling for a few weeks I thought I might try getting it over to my laptop as well. I have the project checked in to a TFS and did a GET in VS2015 on my laptop.

Now when I load the project up on my laptop I get this (see quote below) in the Console in Unity. The interesting thing here is that these dll's are not missing. They are there, and I have given Unity Admin permissions so it should be able to read them no matter what.

I've also gone through all settings in Unity and my stationary and laptop have (as far as I can tell) identical settings. They both also have the same .Net frameworks installed (everything from .Net 2 - 4.6.1).

I have re installed Unity on the laptop with all checkboxes ticked, and both are running Unity 5.4.0f3.

I have read on forums that this can be caused by having .Net 2.0 Subset in the Compatibility setting, but I have .Net 2 and Backend set to IL2CPP.

Also note that I am using OneSignal for push notifications and this is working on my stationary, so I dont think the error is with their dll even though the stacktrace mentions them towards the end.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

> Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException:
>   The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
>
> at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes
>   (bool)
>
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces
>   (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.Type extensionType)
>   [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespace
>   (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000]
>   in :0
>
> at Mono.CSharp.GlobalRootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces
>   (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Mono.CSharp.Driver.LoadReferences () [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in
>   :0
>
> The following assembly referenced from
>   ..\Assets\OneSignal\Platforms\Metro\Newtonsoft.Json.dll could not be
>   loaded:
>        Assembly:   System.Runtime    (assemblyref_index=0)
>        Version:    4.0.0.0
>        Public Key: b03f5f7f11d50a3a The assembly was not found in the Global Assembly Cache, a path listed in the MONO_PATH environment
>   variable, or in the location of the executing assembly
>   (..\Assets\OneSignal\Platforms\Metro).
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. Missing method .ctor in assembly
>   ..\Assets\OneSignal\Platforms\Metro\Newtonsoft.Json.dll, type
>   System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute Can't find custom attr
>   constructor image:
>   ..\Assets\OneSignal\Platforms\Metro\Newtonsoft.Json.dll mtoken:
>   0x0a00003b The following assembly referenced from
>   ..\Assets\OneSignal\Platforms\Metro\OneSignalSDK_WP_WNS.dll could not
>   be loaded:
>        Assembly:   System.Runtime    (assemblyref_index=0)
>        Version:    4.0.10.0
>        Public Key: b03f5f7f11d50a3a The assembly was not found in the Global Assembly Cache, a path listed in the MONO_PATH environment
>   variable, or in the location of the executing assembly
>   (..\Assets\OneSignal\Platforms\Metro).
>
> Missing method .ctor in assembly
>   ..\Assets\OneSignal\Platforms\Metro\OneSignalSDK_WP_WNS.dll, type
>   System.Reflection.AssemblyTrademarkAttribute Can't find custom attr
>   constructor image:
>   ..\Assets\OneSignal\Platforms\Metro\OneSignalSDK_WP_WNS.dll mtoken:
>   0x0a000008